# p-value of pearson correlation of correlated samples

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, independence, degrees-of-freedom, permutation-test

I'm not completely sure if this question has been asked before, but I couldn't find one that suit my problem so far.

So basically I am doing single cell analysis, and I have roughly > 100000 cells or samples (rows), and I calculated the pearson correlation between 2 variables (columns), in this case is gene expression against variable of interest that I call disease score. I have let's say 10000 genes (10000 columns) + 1 column for disease score, and I did correlation test on all the 10000 genes against the disease score. Without checking the null distribution, I just simply converted the Pearson r to t-value with DOF = number_of_cells - 2, and t-value to p. Then, I got a very large number of significantly correlated genes. This, I suppose is due to each cell is not independent of each other which is a well-known property of single-cell analysis. Therefore, assuming DOF = number of cells - 2 is simply incorrect. Then my question is, then how would you calculate p-value of such problem? I was thinking of permutation test, but couldn't wrap my head around as to which should I permute? (Obviously not the cells, since the it will break the cell-dependency). Another idea was to find an effective DOF from covariance matrix perhaps, to see how many independent observations we actually have in our data? Or probably there is some other brilliant work around?

Thanks in advance.

Edit1:
[image]

This t-value distribution looks very unusually normal here, where I expected some sort of a long-tailed distribution, if there is actually some correlated genes. Although Bonferroni correction has been done, it still yields unbelievably high number of significant correlations (~8k out of 17k) with 0.01 cut-off.

Comment: "This, I suppose is due to each cell is not independent of each other which is a well-known property of single-cell analysis." Sure that could have some impact; but I think it has more to do with the fact that n=100000, so tiny effects would tend to show up, even if they were all independent of each other. I don't think changing d.f. nor doing a permutation test would change that (unless you changed the hypothesis at the same time so that you weren't doing thousands of tests). You might want to look into false discovery rates, perhaps

Comment: Well, that could be the case. I've tried bonferonni adjustment, and I still have 10k significant with 0.01 cut-off. Doesn't seem to be believable personally. I will add a screenshot of how the t-value distribution for all ~10,000 tests to show why it doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: With 10000 independent tests, a Bonferroni-adjusted alpha of 0.0001 would correspond to a familywise type I error rate of potentially around 63% (with positively dependent tests it might well be lower though). I'd So if you want to control type I error (which is not what I was suggesting), you'd want it lower than 0.0001. .... again, take a look at procedures for controlling the false discovery rate https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_discovery_rate

Comment: Can you clarify, is each cell independently characterized with respect to its disease status?  Or is the disease status at the individual organism level?  Are the cells all from the same tissue, from the same individual?  Anything else about the design you can tell us?

Comment: No, it's not, there is no disease label in this case, it's a fetal brain dataset coming from 35 different individuals. I have the metadata information for all of the 35 samples, including the fetal's age, brain region (forebrain, midbrain, etc), sex, batch no. (I guess that's all that is relevant to the biology)

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks for the follow up. I am not sure if I follow you. how come Bonferroni-adjust alpha of 0.0001 correspond to FWER type 1 of 63%? 

"FDR-controlling procedures provide less stringent control of Type I errors compared to family-wise error rate (FWER) controlling procedures (such as the Bonferroni correction), which control the probability of at least one Type I error. Thus, FDR-controlling procedures have greater power, at the cost of increased numbers of Type I errors." - Wikipedia

Bonferroni is very stringent on type 1 error afaik.

Comment: Can you please explain what you are trying to achieve? Is this a feature selection problem, i.e. identifying predictors that have the strongest influence on the response? If this is your goal, you might have a look into conditional dependency measures. Moreover, I wonder why you are interested in statistical significance, and not in strength of the correlation (with $n>10^5$, statistical significance should be guaranteed even for extremely weak correlations).

Comment: @AndreasAdinatha thanks, in this case the experimental unit is the 35 individuals not the cell, although the data is observed at the single cell level. Is your correlation analysis adjusted for this clustering?  If not this pseudoreplication would be an explanation as to why you have so much apparent statistical significance.  If I wanted to do a permutation test in this case I would permute the disease status labels between individuals.

Comment: Also take care with the rest of the covariates.

Comment: @cdalitz Actually, this is what I resorted to at the end hahaha... Seems good at least for now. And yeah, actually I also don't really know why, perhaps it's just kinda habitual for me to run significance test to see how many genes or predictors are actually affecting the dependent variable. Because other than statistical test, it just feels arbitrary personally, like for example top 100, or Pearson-r > 0.3. This threshold can be changed to "whatever I feel like it" without any statistical basis. Thanks for the input anyways!

Comment: @GeorgeSavva Actually, I don't have the disease label of the sample as I said. But, I do have a pre-computed disease score for each cell from another software. But, your plan is a good approach in general I guess. I would probably take it like running pseudobulk DE genes. cell-level DE analysis generally give too many false positives even after FDR-adjustment. So what people do is usually collapse the cell-level information to sample-level by summing/averaging the expression of the cells coming from the same sample and run DE analysis on the pseudobulk expression.

Comment: @AndreasAdinatha makes sense. I misunderstood what you meant by having disease scores on cells rather than individuals.  But given the design you have, there's an interesting question about whether you're looking for a correlation within individuals or across individuals.  You should at least stratify your analysis by sample I think.